# Refresh view in HSQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, hsqldb

I would like to update a view in HSQL without writing the same statement again and again.
I have a table CONTACTS with ID, First_NAME and LAST_NAME. I also have a VIEW for this table, which I created with

```
CREATE VIEW IDGREATERTHREE AS SELECT * FROM CONTACTS WHERE ID > 3;
```

How can I update my VIEW after I added a new column to my table. I want to update my table **without** anything like this:

```
ALTER VIEW IDGREATERTHREE AS SELECT * FROM CONTACTS WHERE ID > 3;
```

I would like to find a way to refresh my invalid view in a similar way like in Oracle:

```
ALTER VIEW IDGREATERTHREE COMPILE;
```

I am also looking for a way to select just the invalid views. With`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS` I am not able to see any difference between an invalid and a non-invalid view.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for this would be to write an **`ON DDL`** trigger.

In this `ON DDL` trigger , you check if your modifying your table.

If this is the case, then you use Dynamic SQL to recreate your view. This is doable with [plsql](/questions/tagged/plsql) (you tagged with [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle)). There is ample documentation on creating triggers and dynamic SQL on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

HSQLDB cannot have invalid views. When you create a view, the `SELECT * FROM CONTACTS` is expanded to the actual column names. When you add a column to the table the view is recompiled with the original column names and the new column is not included.